# I want to show cells one by one at Tableview with button

Tags: ios, swift

I do not want to show all items on the tableview. I want to show cells by pushing "go" button. But whenever I run the code below. I got "Fatal Error: Index out of Range"

```
var count = 1
var rowCount: Int = 1 {
    willSet {
        if count != baslik.count {
            count = newValue
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}


var baslik = [String]()
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    cell.textLabel?.text = baslik[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

@IBAction func go(_ sender: UIButton) {
    rowCount += 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

}
```

Comment: Initially, your 'baslik' array has 0 item and rowCount returned is 1. So in 'cellForRowAt' method it tries to access item from first index of array when it has no item.

Comment: Just add temporary source array with cells, which should be displayed, then use this as source data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `baslik` array is empty

```swift
var baslik = [String]()
```

Number of cells starts from 1:

```swift
var count = 1
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return count
}
```

When table try to get item for first cell it crashes:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
...
    cell.textLabel?.text = baslik[indexPath.row] /// 0 is out of range
...
}
```

To prevent this crash start with 0 and increase to 1 only when data arrives:

```swift
var rowCount: Int = 0 {
    willSet {
        rowCount = min(baslik.count, newValue)
    }
    didSet {
        guard oldValue != rowCount else { return }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

var baslik = [String]() {
    didSet {
        rowCount = 1
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return rowCount
}
... rest same
```

Comment: I have server connection. I have data from server. When I make "count", "basilisk.count" It shows all cells. I do not want to show all cells